# Setting empathy's idle time

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, empathy

I'm using Empathy for IM on Ubuntu 10.04. In every IM client I've used since the '90s there's always been a way to set "idle me after X time", at which point it would set you as being away. Empathy seems to do this, but I haven't found a place to specify how long to wait before marking me as away.

Am I missing a plugin or something in the settings? Is this somehow tied in with Gnome and the power setting's idle time? (I'm using a laptop.)

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the help file for empathy it does say "If you do not use your computer for a while, or if the screensaver is on, the status will be automatically set to Away." (on the "change your status" page)
You can edit the length of time before the whole computer is viewed as "idle" in the screensaver preferences.
I've never noticed it before, but you can also choose the screensaver not to be activated when the computer is viewed as idle, the idle probably then just relates to the chat programs.

I would say that the chat status of "Away" is tied to when the computer is classed as "idle" but the screensaver may or may not be running at this time.